# Telegram hyperlinks

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, aiogram

Возникла проблема отправки сообщения в `MarkdownV2`.
Нашел темплейт гиперссылки для телеграма `[Text](Link)`

Написал функцию генерации календаря:

```
def generate_calendar() -> str:
template = '###\n' \
           '[{event_name}]({event_link}) : {from_date} - {to_date} | Format: {format} | Weight: {weight}\n'

calendar = 'Calendar of upcoming events:\n'

for event in get_upcoming_events():
    calendar += template.format(event_name=event.name,
                                event_link=event.link,
                                from_date=event.start_date,
                                to_date=event.finish_date,
                                format=event.format,
                                weight=event.weight
                                )

return markdown_decoration.quote(calendar)
```

Отправил:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['calendar'])
async def command_calendar(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(text=generate_calendar() ,parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

И ссылка не обрабатывается

```
Calendar of upcoming events:
###
[3kCTF-2020](https://ctftime.org/event/1077) : 07/24 17:00 - 07/25 13:00 | Format: Jeopardy | Weight: Undefined
###
[CyBRICS CTF 2020](https://ctftime.org/event/1012) : 07/25 10:00 - 07/26 10:00 | Format: Jeopardy | Weight: 24.09
###
[InCTF 2020](https://ctftime.org/event/981) : 07/31 13:30 - 08/02 13:30 | Format: Jeopardy | Weight: 53.95
###
[DEF CON CTF 2020](https://ctftime.org/event/1088) : 08/07 17:00 - 08/09 21:00 | Format: Attack-Defense | Weight: Undefined
###
[PoseidonCTF 1st Edition](https://ctftime.org/event/1049) : 08/08 17:00 - 08/09 17:00 | Format: Jeopardy | Weight: Undefined
```

UPD: Нашел метод класса `markdown_decoration` - `link`, но с ним ситуация та же самая (очевидно потому что реализация метода такая же, как и моя):

```
markdown_decoration.link(event.name, event.link)
```

Не понимаю почему;

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что я делал

```
return markdown_decoration.quote(calendar)
```

тем самым убивая саму разметку.